# Alamofire request with Header?

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire

I'm trying to make a call to an API that now requires a Client ID as a header.

I don't know if I'm anywhere close here but this is what I attempted:

```
let clientID = "theclientIDIGotFromtheWebsite"

    let urlString = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/"

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "ClientID": clientID
    ]

    Alamofire.request(urlString, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
}
```

I get back an error : message = "No client id specified";

The same as if you click the link: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/

The mini-guide I followed to get the clientID is this: https://blog.twitch.tv/client-id-required-for-kraken-api-calls-afbb8e95f843#.27gij8pj9

The clientID I've put in is 100% correct, I've checked a few times.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "mini-guide" uses the key `"Client-ID"` instead of `"ClientID"`